# I keep getting "undefined" as an error, function not returning anything

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to figure out why I keep getting undefined, and I don't really see why, I know that I would get undefined if my function isn't returning anything, but in this case, even with returning in two places, I am still getting undefined. I think that the reason for that is that maybe I am not returning the value from `innerFunc` properly? I'm thinking maybe there's something wrong with my syntax here: `innerFunc(arg)` but I'm not sure how it is wrong, or what to change it to.

Any help would be appreciated.

***Instructions:***

Create a function "fastCache" that takes one argument (a function) and returns a function. When fastCache is invoked it creates an object that tracks calls to the returned function, where each input to the returned function is associated with its output. Every subsequent call to that returned function with the same argument will return the output directly from the object, instead of invoking the original function again.

```
function fastCache(func) { 
  const obj = {};
  
  function innerFunc(arg) {
   for (const key in obj) {
     if (key === arg) {
       return obj[arg]
     } else {
       obj[arg] = innerFunc(arg)
       return innerFunc(arg)
       console.log(obj[arg])
       console.log(arg)
       console.log(innerFunc(arg))
     }
   } 

 }
  return innerFunc
   // console.log(innerFunc(arg))
}

//example:
//SINGLE ARGUMENT CASE
const multiplyBy2 = num => num * 2;
const cachedMultiplyBy2 = fastCache(multiplyBy2);
```

Comment: Why does your function have a function in it?

Comment: This `innerFunc` looks really...not optimal. Why loop over all properties? Why set `obj[arg]` for each `key`? I think you need to re-visit how that works.

Comment: Because it is a function that accepts a function, and returns a function.

Comment: It's more conventional to use anonymous functions than named ones for this purpose, or even better, `=>` style functions.

Comment: Because each key of the object is assigned the value of running innerFunc with that argument. Every arg passed to `innerFunc` is stored as a key in the object (key-value pairs), with the value being the output.

Comment: It's far from clear why you need a loop at all.

Comment: The **answer to your question** is simply this: **The condition in the `for()` loop will always, every time, not have anything to iterate** - that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a simple cache function:

```js
    function cacheWrapper(fn) {
      let cache = { };

      return arg => {
        if (cache.hasOwnProperty(arg)) {
          return cache[arg];
        }

        return cache[arg] = fn(arg);
      };
    }
    
    function test(x) {
      return x * 2;
    }
    
    let testCached = cacheWrapper(test);
    
    console.log(testCached(2));
    console.log(testCached(2));
```

The key here is [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) which will tell you if that cache slot is occupied or not. This avoids having to fumble around and find out the hard way with iteration.

Comment: So if I understand this properly, the result of the inner (anonymous) function is running the function that is passed into cacheWrapper with the argument that is passed into the inner function? So `test(2)` in this case, right? @tadman

Comment: Yeah, it just passes through a single argument.

Answer (score 0):

If the number isn't already in the object, it won't be found in the loop.

```
function fastCache(func) { 
  const obj = {};
  
  function innerFunc(arg) {
   for (const key in obj) {
     if (key === arg) {
       return obj[arg]
     }
   } 

   obj[arg] = func(arg)
   return func(arg)

 }
  return innerFunc
   // console.log(innerFunc(arg))
}

//example:
//SINGLE ARGUMENT CASE
const multiplyBy2 = num => num * 2;
const cachedMultiplyBy2 = fastCache(multiplyBy2); 
const result = cachedMultiplyBy2(8);
```

Comment: So you know why my code wasn't returning anything though? Was it because I had the return func(arg) inside of the else statement within that 'for...in' loop?